# Decreasing refresh time for Skim app (macOS High Sierra)?

Tags: texlive, compiling, mac, viewers

Is there any way to decrease the interval between compilation and the point when Skim refreshes its display of the corresponding PDF?  It seems to take quite a bit longer than on my old Windows Vista machine with MiKTeX and Sumatra PDF.

For reference, I am using macOS High Sierra and Aquamacs with AucTeX and TeXLive.